# CustomMembership Provider in SharePoint Job

Tags: timer-jobs, sql-membership-provider

I recently developed a Custom Membership provider to manage users in SharePoint 2013. And I want to use this provider in SharePoint Job to renitialise all users passwords periodicaly. The problem is the Provider Configuration is added only to the Sites webconfigs , so in the context of owstimer the Provider configuration is missing and I don't want to modify the owstimer.exe.config. What the best alternative for this situation?

Something like :

Update:
Finaly to get around this, I used a WCF Service, Hosted within my SharePoint Site.

Thankx

Comment: What sort of configs do you need to read? Could you add them to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly what you are trying to accomplish from your code, but you have a couple of options to store the configurations within SharePoint.

**Option 1**

Use a settings list: This preferable if you have a root site collection or site. This list would just two fields setting name (or title), and setting value.

**Option 2**

Use the web application's property bag. This is more or less a Hashtable that will allow you to store settings. Then, from the timer job you can point the web application where the job is running under and read the property values.

For more info: [SPWebApplication.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppersistedobject.properties.aspx)

-Hope it helps